# Memory use when replacing for loops with list comprehensions in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Often in Haskell, one writes code like `sum [x|x<-[1..n],x satisfies some predicate]`. I understand that lazy evaluation can make things like this more efficient, for example the `and` function will stop evaluating a list as soon as it sees a single `false`. So will Haskell evaluate the entire list in the first case I mentioned, wasting tons of memory, or will lazy evaluation somehow make it as efficient as a tail-recursive or iterative approach?

Comment: Have you tried it? `sum` is a little weird, but imagine defining `sum' = foldl' (+) 0`. Can you see why that won't run out of memory?

Comment: @dfeuer I'm a complete noob, you're going to have to explain :).

Comment: The reason that `sum` does not run out of memory is complicated--it depends on compiler optimizations. But you can write your own version of `sum` that is easily seen to be space-safe.

Comment: When you say, "lazy evaluation can make things like this more efficient", what does "more efficient" mean? More efficient than what, exactly? What are you hoping will happen that means you can compute a sum without computing all the numbers that go into the sum? (There *are* cases where that can make sense -- but I want to make sure to answer the question you're actually asking, and it's not clear at the moment exactly what you're asking about.)

Comment: Search for "list fusion". It's a general technique that allows to completely remove all intermediate lists from that kind of computation, effectively turning the functional code into imperative for loops. See: https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC_optimisations#Fusion   and   the paper *Stream Fusion: From Lists to Streams to Nothing at All, Coutts, Leshchinskiy and Stewart, 2007*.  But this kind of approach is a bit limited. It works fine when you use functions defined in terms of `fold`s and built-in functions, but will fail when you use recursive definitions.

Comment: @Bakuriu, at this level, I think it means "won't blow the cache if the list is long, and won't blow the heap if it's longer".

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, the reason `sum` tends not to run programs out of memory is complicated, and relies on compiler trickery. Therefore, I'll answer your question based on a let's-pretend world where `sum` is defined differently. GHC tries very hard to turn the real version into something more like the let's-pretend version whenever it can, so this is not too far from the truth. Let's pretend:

```
sum :: Num a => [a] -> a
sum xs = sumWith 0 xs

sumWith :: Num a => a -> [a] -> a
sumWith acc [] = acc
sumWith acc (x : xs) =
  let acc' = acc + x
  in acc' `seq` sumWith acc' xs
```

The detailed mechanics of `[x | x <- [1..n], p x]` are also a bit complicated, but you seem to be okay with the assumption that its elements are generated lazily, which is about all you need to know to consider the sum. For simplicity's sake, let's drop the predicate and just consider `sum [1..3]`:

```
sum [1..3]
==>
sumWith 0 [1..3]
==>  -- pattern match on [1..3], forcing the first `(:)` constructor
let acc' = 0 + 1
in acc' `seq` sumWith acc' [2..3]
==> -- forcing acc' `seq` ... forces acc'
sumWith 1 [2..3]
==> -- pattern match on the list
let acc' = 1 + 2
in acc' `seq` sumWith acc' [3..3]
==> force acc'
sumWith 3 [3..3]
==>
let acc' = 3 + 3
in acc' `seq` sumWith acc' []
==>
sumWith 6 []
==>
6
```

As you can see, the `seq` forces the term to collapse down to its original size each time we take a step, so we operate in constant memory. In fact, GHC can do even better—various optimizations can often lead to this allocating no memory at all and operating entirely in CPU registers.

#### The real `sum`

The real `sum` is peculiar; I'd call it a historical artifact. It is *missing* the critical `seq`, so its definition is roughly equivalent to

```
sum :: Nom a => [a] -> a
sum xs = sumWith 0 xs

sumWith :: Num a => a -> [a] -> a
sumWith acc [] = acc
sumWith acc (x : xs) = sumWith (acc + x) xs
```

If you go through this step by step like I did above, you'll see that it *doesn't* operate in constant space, because the accumulator term will keep growing. It starts at `0`, then goes to `0 + 1`, then `0 + 1 + 2`, then `0 + 1 + 2 + 3`. Whoops! Fortunately, GHC can generally patch this problem up. It uses something called "demand analysis", a variety of "strictness analysis", to figure out that it can force the accumulator on each step without changing the meaning of the program. So it does that, and everything generally works out okay.

#### The *real* real `sum`

I've still been lying a bit, because the *real* `sum` is actually defined, these days, for all `Foldable` containers, and its definition for lists is really

```
sum = foldl (+) 0
```

`foldl`, in turn, is actually defined (for lists) as

```
foldl :: forall a b. (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldl k z0 xs =
  foldr (\(v::a) (fn::b->b) -> oneShot (\(z::b) -> fn (k z v))) (id :: b -> b) xs z0
```

Whaaaaat? Well, that `oneShot` is a bit of primitive magic to guide the optimizer. We can take it out and simplify things a bit:

```
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldl k z0 xs = foldr (\v fn z -> fn (k z v)) id xs z0
```

I'm not going to go into detail here about how this "`foldl` as `foldr`" definition works—you can find various explanations around. But this strange definition is tied up with the list fusion magic Bakuriu mentioned in a comment. In particular, `foldr` combines nicely with lots of things by way of compiler rewrite rules in the list library.